# How to center CSS Grid but child elements at the start?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to implement this layout with CSS Grid or Flexbox. If necessary, it is also possible to use JS.

[image]

In the pictures you can see how the child elements should be arranged when adding 1, 2, 3 and 4 child elements in a sequence

The content is generated dynamically. TThat is, the number of child elements is unknown. There may be a maximum of 3 child elements in a row. The grid items should be centered. The whole Layout should also be responsive.

```css
.parent {
  background-color: red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  /* 3* 350px width of child elements + 2*20px gap*/
  max-width: 1090px; 
  padding: 20px;
}

.child {
  width: 350px;
  height: 450px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

It is currently not responsive (if possible without media queries) and the child elements are not centered.

Do you know how I can implement this layout?

Comment: How are the children being added? Is it via php on load? if so you could add a class based on the array length and style accordingly.

Comment: The children are added via js with a render function. Row 3 will look exactly like row 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't define 3 columns but rely on implicit column creation:

```css
.parent {
  background-color: red;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: calc((100% - 2*20px)/3); /* size of one column */
  grid-gap: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px;
}

.child {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

/* place each item in the adequate column */
.child:nth-child(3n + 1) {grid-column: 1}
.child:nth-child(3n + 2) {grid-column: 2}
.child:nth-child(3n + 3) {grid-column: 3}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution is good. Can this be done responsively without media queries? Just like flexbox with flex-wrap?

Comment: @coder where do you see media query in my solution?

Comment: there is no media query.  But the solution is not responsive. For example on mobile device should be only one column per row.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have something for this using implicit grids:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 50px;
  background: #000;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #666;
}

.grid-inner {
  display: grid;
  gap: 30px;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-auto-columns: calc(33% - 15px);
}

.box {
  padding: 30px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: 3;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="grid-inner">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="grid-inner">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="grid-inner">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="grid-inner">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</section>

<section>
  <div class="grid-inner">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```